# AVAudioPlayer cannot play MP3 file

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer, audiotoolbox

I have two MP3 files. I'm able to play the 1st file, but not the second one on iOS.

I'm using AVAudioPlayer to play them.

The first file which I'm able to **play** has the following information.

```
0000000 49 44 33 03 00 00 00 00 21 76 54 49 54 32 00 00
0000010 00 11 00 00 00 4e 68 6f 74 65 20 4d 61 20 53 65
0000020 74 20 4e 61 65 4d 43 44 49 00 00 00 aa 00 00 45


played.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, 
v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo
```

The clip I'm **not able to play** has the following info.

```
0000000 49 44 33 04 00 00 00 00 00 5b 54 50 45 31 00 00
0000010 00 0a 00 00 03 43 6f 6c 64 70 6c 61 79 00 54 49
0000020 54 32 00 00 00 08 00 00 03 59 65 6c 6c 6f 77 00

yellow.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III,  
v2.5,  24 kbps, 8 kHz, Monaural
```

I'm pulling my hair because I can play both of them fine on my mac using VLC or iTunes. However, my iOS player cannot handle the second clip.

What's wrong in the second one?

This is the one I can play. https://www.dropbox.com/s/l93b4f4n63oihf0/cut.mp3?dl=0

This is the one I cannot play.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xrpyxwzqhb7dzf/yellow.mp3?dl=0

Thanks.

Comment: are you able to play that audio outside the ios . I mean in itunes or quick player ?

Comment: @Muhammad yup. I was able to play them.

Comment: @Muhammad i've added the link see if you can play them?

Comment: Yes working, you have not posted relevant code .Check below answer. Audio is playing perfectly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working fine for me. check below code

**Objective C**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController ()
{
    AVAudioPlayer *_audioPlayer;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Construct URL to sound file
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/yellow.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    // Create audio player object and initialize with URL to sound
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
    [_audioPlayer play];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

**Swift**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("yellow", ofType: "mp3")
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))
            audioPlayer .play()
        }
        catch {
            print("Something bad happened. Try catching specific errors to narrow things down")
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```